# Mozilla Firefox browser not load the style sheet

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, caching

I converted the client website into responsive website so shifted the maximum internal and inline css code into external stylesheet so i can target the element as per screen sizes.

here is the client website [Photovoltaiksolarstorm.com](http://www.photovoltaiksolarstrom.de/)

Website work fine on every browser chrome, opera, safari and others but on mozilla it doesn't load exact css file seems like file is loaded somewhere on server cache so i cleared my browser cache completely and client asked the server host for cache issue but they said everything is fine her still the problem occured. i am sharing screenshot of website one area there are many like that but i hope one can debug from there:

Right screenshot from chrome:  http://www.photovoltaiksolarstrom.de/photovoltaik-rechner - page link
[image: http://www.photovoltaiksolarstrom.de/photovoltaik-rechner]

right screen shot of mozilla browser.
[image]

Website is on wordpress, i shifted it to bootstrap. please let me know what is the issue there.
 Many thanks.

Comment: I don't have your problem on the newest firefox. make sure you have an up-to-date FF.  But: `17:40:16.609 no element found1 30e7e95b756d326edea067f26ccee18a2c426d1b:1:1
` Maybe that helps

Comment: Hey buddy,thanks for checking but i don't understand 17:40:16.609 no element found1 30e7e95b756d326edea067f26ccee18a2c426d1b:1:1 this.

Comment: @Ahbi I toke a closer look later on and when I opened the file that is producing that error it was empty so that's why `no element found` I think.

Comment: I didn't understand mate look something very strange. can you explain what is this exactly.

Comment: When I click on the error in the webconsole, there opens a window with the error file loaded so that you can see the error. That window is empty when I click on the error so I think that the browser is saying with `no element found` that there is nothing in that file or in other words: the file is empty. But like I told, I am not sure that if this is right explaination of the error, this is what I think.

Comment: The CSS simply doesn't validate. See my answer. There are loads of errors. It's a miracle it works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a parsing error. Right above your `rechner-paratop` class there is the following line:

```
.author{font-style:italic;color:#222222;"}
```

The quote `"` at the end right before the closing bracket is clearly wrong. This might stop some browsers from properly parsing your CSS.

Edit: Taking a closer look at your CSS clearly shows that there are more validation problems.

Comment: thanks but there are other places also where i facing css issue sir.

Comment: Well, you're lucky that your design works at all. Validating your CSS yields 2 errors and 8 warnings. Fix these along with the error in my answer above.

Comment: thanks fed for quick reply i am going to fix them asap.

Comment: If i am right fed there are issue with   min_search_engine_v2.css  file ?  and the above parsing issue with style.css